# Rails Security Patch: SQL Injection Flaw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sql-injection

I need to apply the latest Rails security patch from the newly discovered SQL injection flaw.

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and found this patch file ( https://rubyonrails-security.googlegroups.com/attach/23daa048baf28b64/3-2-dynamic_finder_injection.patch?pli=1&view=1&part=5 ) but I'm unsure how I use this file to patch my Rails code.

How do I get to the files mentioned in the git change set? Is there a simple way to implement this patch?

Comment: Why not update the rails gems?

Comment: I will eventually update the rails gem but I have a ton of gems which may interfere with the upgrade, so I'd like to do a quick patch first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `git help am` to get the details on how to apply these type of patches.  Should be as simple as downloading the file, cd'ing into the activerecord directory and typing `git am < filename`.

But if you can... update the gems... more PITA now, but better down the road...

Comment: Part of the problem is that the file patches both activerecord and activesupport, which, to my knowlegde are separate gems.